# Instagram JSON response redirecting to login [Discord JS and Heroku]

Tags: javascript, json, heroku, instagram, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot, more precisely learning how to.
If I run the bot locally on my own computer, it returns the correct json response, with all the profile details and etc, but if I host it on Heroku I get the following error in Heroku logs

```
2020-06-09T23:47:45.215756+00:00 app[worker.1]: An error occurred: FetchError: invalid json response body at https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/gucci/%3F__a%3D1 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

if I go to the link in the error:
`https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/gucci/%3F__a%3D1`

I'm greeted with the login form. How can I bypass this?

Again, it works perfectly fine if I run the bot in my own computer. It only happens when I host it on Heroku. This is the fetch code.

```js
const igUsername = args[0].toLowerCase();
const url = `http://www.instagram.com/${igUsername}/?__a=1`;
const res = await fetch(url).then(resUrl => resUrl.json()).catch(err => {
   console.log(`An error occurred: ${err}`);
   return message.reply('Something went wrong! If this isn\'t fixed in the next hour, please appeal a complaint in my discord server!');
});
```

Comment: The reason it works on your computer is prob because you are logged into instagram, heroku isn't however. You will have to use the instagram api to access it or find some way to login to instagram via heroku

Comment: @Karizma I tried it with logging out as well, still worked, besides, wouldn't the login information be stored in the browser instead of the computer? node-fetch would have it's own 'browser' or whatever it uses, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment but the issue is your server's ip has been flagged they only allow consumer device ips to query it because of limiting